# С помощью каких классов и методов можно решить следующую задачу о распараллеливании?

Tags: c#, распараллеливание

Запутался во всём многообразии статей на MSDN.

Имеется список объектов (процессов), у каждого из которых условно указано значение CPU burst, которое означает сколько мс будет простаивать поток, имитируя "выполнение процесса".

Нужно сформировать пул из N потоков (число задаётся из внешнего файла). Каждый поток должен забирать последний элемент из списка и "обрабатывать" его (ожидать нужное время). После того, как "обработка" закончится, поток должен брать из списка ещё один объект, пока они не закончатся. При этом к списку одновременно должен иметь доступ только один поток (остальные ждут своей очереди).

Comment: а вопрос-то в чем? (то, что указано в заголовке таковым вряд ли может считаться - слишком уж общий характер)

Comment: Ну, мне нужно найти любой способ реализации описанного в вопросе.

Comment: @InfernumDeus: Ну например, посмотрите [сюда](/research/221526/).